# What does it mean "контора дурку гонит"?

Tags: значения, idioms

I could not reconstruct the meaning using the dictionaries.

Comment: To all the good answers I'd add one thing. All answers say that "контора" is some organization. This is true, but sometimes it is said figuratively, and may mean any organization, even just some single person or a group (gang) of people. And considering that the whole phrase is slang (figurative), such usage, referring to not an official organization, but simply an entity, is far more likely to be the case. So, I'd say it means "the entity is trying to fool [me]".

Comment: To play fool. Also, don't take on account the foolish answer about evil lying KGB. The author does дурку гонит.

Answer (score 5):

"Контора дурку гонит" can mean that "the organization (контора) is **intentionally** acting in a wrong way (гонит дурку), **pretending** that they incorrectly understand your requests.

This meaning was shown in a [sketch by Arkadii Raikin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ei_dztACr14) where "organization" imitates that client's order and requests on "насосы" (pumps) that they cannot produce, are understood on their end as "колеса" (wheels) that they have produced, packed and sent to the client.

Answer (score 3):

*Дурка* (slang) usually means *bedlam*, *madhouse*, but here it stands for *psychopathy*, *madness*. So *гнать дурку* (or *гнать дуру*, *включить дуру*, *гнать дурочку* etc.) means *to simulate mental disorder* --> *to deceive someone* (cf. *Что ты мне дурочку гонишь?* = *Trying to fool me?*).

*Контора* here is close to "*Company*". It could be just "some organization" or specifically FSB (cf. Company = CIA). That depends on the context.

So the whole expression is to be interpreted as "**the company fools [someone]**". Whatever it means.

Comment: `гнать дуру, включить дуру, гнать дурочку` never means, at least I've never heard this for my 30 years, `to simulate mental disorder`. It means `to pretend to be a muggle, a fool` for some purpose. For instance, an employee didn't work all the day, because the boss was absent. Then, when the boss asked, 'Why you did nothing yesterday?' the employee responds, 'I thought it was a holiday'. This is no way `to simulate mental disorder`

Comment: @user907860 So what's the _real_ difference between "to pretend to be a fool for some purpose" and "to simulate mental disorder"? Also [гнать дуру](http://fenya.academic.ru/1059/%D0%93%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83) originates from criminal jargon. Non-argo variant would be "прикинуться дураком".

Comment: The difference is that to be a fool is not a mental disorder. A mental disorder is something like schizophrenia etc., which requires a treatment in mental hospital. If you dropped from the ninth grade of school or cannot say what is the square root of 100 https://youtu.be/bEmEeuFyUog?t=3m43s you are a stupid fool, but this is not a mental disorder

Comment: "to simulate mental disorder" in Russian is `косить под психа`, an official variant - `симулировать псих. заболевание` etc. `включить дуру` is a totally different thing

Comment: @user907860 Ещё раз, "гнать дуру" - это изначально воровской жаргон (ссылку я выше дал), а воры именно симулируют псих.заболевания, а не просто дурачатся. Понятно, что в повседневной речи употребление немножко изменилось. Потому я через стрелочку и написал "симулировать"->"дурачить".

Comment: поудалял все последние комментарии, т.к. придумал намного лучший способ объяснить почему "включить/гнать дурака/дурку" ни в коем случае не есть "to simulate a mental disorder". Возьмите в гугле забейте "включил дурака" или "стал гнать дурку" и посмотрите результаты, т.е. в каких ситуациях это выражение используется. А потом забейте "стал косить под психа". И вы увидите, что "to simulate a mental disorder" это как раз второй случай и никак не первый. Т.е. ваш ответ неверный и сбивает с толку тех, кто только учит язык

Answer (score 1):

It means "the organization is acting in a wrong way," and it is not possible to translate it more precisely since the context is lacking. Please, provide the context.

Answer (score 0):

The exact translation depends on the context.
Generally meaning 'office wants to fool me'. "Office" — Government, Police, Firm, Company, etc.

Comment: "Somebody wants me to do something" means "somebody wants that **I** should do something." You probably wanted to say "office wants to fool me"? This or that way, your answer is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

*Гнать дурку* (сленг) - лгать, обманывать, вводить в заблуждение. *Контора* - так в СССР называли КГБ. Сейчас так могут называть ФСБ, МВД и другие официальные государственные структуры. Фразу *контора дурку гонит* можно "перевести" на литературный русский язык как, например, *правительство (ФСБ, МВД) лжёт (вводит в заблуждение)*...

*Гнать дурку* (slang) - to lie, to deceive, to mislead. *Контора* - in the USSR was called the KGB. So now you can call the FSB, interior Ministry and other official government agencies. The phrase *контора дурку гонит* can be "translated" into the literary Russian language as, for example, the government (FSB, MVD) is lying (misleading)...

Comment: КГБ? Really? LOL.

Comment: Да, в самом деле.

Comment: "Контора" - может означать любую организацию. "Контора дурку гонит" - может быть "Поставщик опять задерживает поставку под нелепыми предлогами"

Comment: Может, не спорю.